# understanding getter methods and instance variables

Tags: variables, instance

If a class has 5 instance variables, what's the most number of getter methods that it can have? I'm not sure and need help with this topic, can someone please answer this? Thank You.

Comment: In what context did this question come up that made you want to come here and ask. It would be better to ask about that thing instead.

Comment: I'm talking in general, like what about if a class had 10 instance variables, THEN how many getter methods would it have... something like that...

Comment: And what happened that makes you want to know? The answer to your question as-is is "As many as you need" but I doubt that is helpful to you, what is the problem you are trying to solve that knowing this piece of information will help you solve it.

Comment: I'm familiar with instance variables, but am not good with getter methods. I'm learning programming and don't really know what a getter method is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have X class members and you want a getter for each member than you need X getters.